# Is there a metaphorical meaning to this line? (心の望むままに情欲を唄おう)

Tags: meaning, metaphor

The line in question:

> 心の望むままに情欲を唄おう。

Context: The speaker is monologuing about how terrible society is, especially how corrupt those in power are, he starts to sound nihilistic and basically says he'll act like a criminal because that's what society wants him to act like.

> 見下される程度の、唾棄される程度の悪に何の意味があろうか。全てがペテンなのだ。自分がその嘘に乗らずしてどうする。ああ、心の望むままに情欲を唄おう。

He then mentions the many ways this world could end up being destroyed, by the greed of those in power, by enemies waging war on them etc. But when the world does end he is determined to be a criminal until those final days.

Now back to the question, I don't understand what the speaker means by "心の望むままに情欲を唄おう", translating it literally gives me an odd result "(I/they?) will sing their desires as much as they wish" so I'm thinking there's a more metaphorical meaning behind this that I don't know about yet. I know "心の望むままに" is a set phrase that means "as much as your heart desires" but the  情欲を唄おう is quite confusing. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

情欲を唄う is *not* an idiomatic set phrase with a surprising metaphorical meaning. うたう can take various objects and mean something along the lines of "to sing about ～". For example 愛を歌う is "to sing about love", 春を俳句に詠う is "to recite/compose a haiku about spring". I think it tends to imply the object is something to be celebrated or glorified.

Comment: I see, so perhaps the line is simply supposed to mean "I will sing my passions to my heart's content".